# ¿Mostrar datos relacionados con un foreach en Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

tengo dos tablas una llamada "**Events**" y otra "**Dependences**", una dependence puede tener varios **event**, esa es la relación entre ellas, lo que trato de hacer es mostrar los datos de un **event**, pero también mostrar los datos de la **dependence** a la cual esta relacionada.

este es mi controllador donde traigo el **event**:

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function inicio(){
        $events = Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('status', 'PUBLISHED')->paginate(3);
        return view('welcome', compact('events'));
    }
```

este es el modelo de **event**:

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';

    protected $fillable = [
        'admin_id', 'dependence_id', 'place_id', 'name', 'slug', 'excerpt', 'body', 'status', 'file'
    ];



    public function dependences(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Dependence', 'dependence_id');
    }
```

modelo de **dependence**:

```
class Dependence extends Model
{
    protected $table = "dependences";

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'slug'
    ];

    public function events(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
    }
```

así trato de mostrarlo en la vista:

```
 @foreach($event->dependences as $dependence)
                <a href="#">
                {{$dependence->name}}
                </a>
                @endforeach
```

pero me aparece este error:
**Trying to get property 'name' of non-object**

estas son las tablas en la base de datos: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las rutas están bien, pero no se a que se debe el problema, espero su ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola @Talked, de casualidad tu base de datos `dependences` incluye algo tipo `event_id`?

Comment: saludos @Talked prueba de este modo y me dices que tal `@foreach($events as $event)
 {{ $event->name }}
 {{ $event->slug }}
@foreach($event->events as $e)
 {{ $e->name }}
 {{ $e->slug }}
 {{ $e->excerpt }}
@endforeach`

Comment: @JesúsMagallón no, en la tabla dependences no tengo un columna con event_id

Comment: @AlfredoPaz hola, me aparece este error, Undefined variable: events

Comment: Talked, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Creo que ayudaría mucho que muestres lo que arroja un **`var_dump($event);`**, así podremos verificar el objeto que se está creando y sobre el que se quiere interactuar. Por ejemplo, si `$event` es un array en vez de un objeto, es evidente que no podrás leerlo de ese modo, sino así: `$dependence["name"]`

Comment: @A.Cedano hola, esto es lo que arroja el var_dum($event) object(App\Event)#522 (26) { ["table":protected]=> string(6) "events" ["fillable":protected]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "admin_id" [1]=> string(13) "dependence_id" [2]=> string(8) "place_id" [3]=> string(4) "name" [4]=> string(4) "slug" [5]=> string(7) "excerpt" [6]=> string(4) "body" [7]=> string(6) "status" [8]=> string(4) "file" } ["connection":protected]=> string(5) "mysql" ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["withCou....

Comment: Exacto, el `var_dump` indica en efecto que es un objeto, **peeeeero**  indica también que, **la propiedad `name`  se encuentra dentro de un array de ese objeto, cuya clave es `fillable`**. Eso significa que tu bucle debe escribirse así: `@foreach($event->fillable as $dependence)` ... De ese modo debería funcionar.

Comment: @A.Cedano hola, gracias por responder, aun me sigue saliendo error, es este "Invalid argument supplied for foreach() " , fillable no es el método de event con dependences.

Comment: Talked, viendo más de cerca el `var_dump`, me parece que tienes algún problema en alguna parte. Lamentablemente no sé usar Laravel, por lo que no te puedo dar datos más precisos. Lo cierto es que tu objeto `$events` no tiene una propiedad `name`. El objeto tiene una propiedad `fillable` que es un array, y dentro de ese array hay una posición `3` que equivale a `name`. Si es eso lo que te interesa, podrás acceder a ella de este modo: `@foreach($event->fillable as $dependence) <a href="#">
 {{$dependence[3]}} </a>
 @endforeach` en cuyo caso, lo único que te imprimirá será `name`.

Comment: @A.Cedano ok, gracias por tu tiempo, seguiré intentando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es simple, solo confundes el tipo de dato que te retorna `dependences` de tu modelo **Event**, te explico como:

Cuanto se tiene una función en tu modelo que enlace a otro hay tener en cuenta que tipo de dato retornas, en tu caso tienes:

```
public function dependences(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Dependence', 'dependence_id');
}
```

Lo cual esta bien ya que segun tu explicación **un event pertenece a una dependece** y **una dependence tiene varios event**, entonces al hacer `belongsTo` (traducido a:**pertenece a**) lo que retornas es un `objeto` del modelo **Dependence**.

algo similar pasa en tu modelo **Dependence**:

```
public function events(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Event');
}
```

Pero en este caso tienes un `hasMany` (traducido a:**Tiene muchos**), dicha función retorna un `array` de **Event**.

> para resumir uno retorna un **objeto** y el otro un **array de objetos**

Hasta ahí la explicación y la verdad todo esta muy bien pero...

Ahora la **SOLUCION**

Suponiendo que `$event` es un objeto entonces `$event->dependences` retorna un objeto, este no puede ser recorrido por un foreach, entonces lo que se debe de hacer es:

```
$event->dependences->name;//para acceder al nombre de dependencia
```

En otro caso con `$dependence->events` retorna un array y ahí si puede utilizar un array:

```
@foreach($dependence->events as $event)
    {{$event->name}}
@endforeach
```

Hasta ahí la solucion, pero...

Ahora un **consejo**:

cuando tu realizas:

```
$events = Event::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('status', 'PUBLISHED')->paginate(3);
```

**NO ACLARAS** que relaciones te traes con él, lo cual **esta mas o menos regular**, ya que laravel siendo tan intuitivo y eficas se lleva todas con él.

> pero tambien ahi podria radicar tu error!!!

te aconsejo siempre utilizar `with`, dicha funcion nos permite decidir que relaciones extraeremos en la consulta.

```
$events = Event::with('dependences')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->where('status', 'PUBLISHED')->paginate(3);
```

Teniendo `$events`lo siguiente no deberia fallar

```
@foreach($events as $event)
    {{$event->name}}//nombre del event
    <br>
    {{$event->dependences->name}}//nombre de dependence del event
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

No sé si lo habrás probado, pero yo creo que en la vista, te falta que sea función, es decir, debería ser así el foreach:

```
@foreach($event->dependences() as $dependence)
```